# Does java uses more than one process to run the code

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

how does the multi-threading in java works? if I create a bunch of threads how JVM allocates those threads across the processes. and if threads are created across the processes will the context switching be costly?

Comment: JVM allocates only one process. And it can run as many threads as needed within this single process.

Comment: A multithreaded Java program contains multiple threads running concurrently within a program, where each thread is performing some specific task.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov so there is no way java uses more than one process to run the code ?

Comment: @sairamcharan, technically, it depends on a JVM implementation. But on practice I don't know a JVM that occupies more than one process. Surely, if you want to, you can run another JVM from your code and create one more process, but that would be two different JVMs.